# Nginx directory when build from source?

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, web-server

I wanted to install **nginx-push-stream-module** with Nginx so I followed the steps as given here [nginx-push-stream-module](https://github.com/wandenberg/nginx-push-stream-module#installation-)

Now the problem is that I cannot find my nginx directory, usally it should be /etc/nginx.

What is the correct way to get thing up and running?

Comment: At line three of the linked code, the variable `NGINX_PUSH_STREAM_MODULE_PATH` is being set.

Comment: @gf isn't it a temporary path to compile nginx-push-stream with nginx

Comment: No, because further down, "test configuration" and "run", a config file out of this directory is being used.

Comment: @gf_ it doesn't work on a new terminal instance

Comment: What doesn't work? Please try to give some details, so people are actually able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

In this example the `PREFIX` is defaulted, so basically `etc` should reside in the `/usr/local/nginx`. After all, it's just a directory, create it.